# How can I make sure that the recursion terminates?

Tags: c, recursion

In this Example the function terminates in a strange way, although the values don't change (no base case is reached)

```
#include<stdio.h>


int power(int a, int b);


int main(){

    int a;
    int b;
    printf(" Enter number: ");
    scanf(" %d",&a);
    printf(" Enter it's power: ");
    scanf( " %d",&b);
    printf("\n\n Result: %d",power(a,b));
}

int power(int a, int b){

    if( b == 0)
    return 1;
    if ( a == 0)
    return 0;
    if ( b == 1)
    return a;
    else return a*(b,a); //shouldn't it be: "else return a*(a,b-1);" , how does this work!
}
```

Comment: What recursion? What input are you using? What are the results and what did you expect?

Comment: you should try printing a and b to see whats going on while the functions execute. You arent using any recursion in the code you provided.

Comment: (`b,a)` does not what you think it does. Read about the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Answer (score 1):

This function is actually *not* recursive since it's not calling itself:

```
else return a*(b,a);
```

All it's doing is returning `a*a`.  It should be:

```
else return a*power(a,b-1);
```